# Sum the values of multiple rows with the same column value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following structure:

```
+====================================================================+
+     City    |    PartyName    |    VoteCount    |  VotePercentage  +
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ City1       | Party1          | 871             | 1.2              +
+ City2       | Party1          | 580             | 2.3              +
+ City3       | Party1          | 149             | 1.2              +
+ City1       | Party2          | 234             | 0.2              +
+ City2       | Party2          | 533             | 1.3              +
+ City3       | Party2          | 655             | 2.2              +
+====================================================================+
```

This table shows the votes per political party per city. I need a query that sums all the vote counts and percentages of each party. So the above table should look like:

```
+=======================================================+
+    PartyName    |    VoteCount    | VotePercentage    +
+-------------------------------------------------------+
+ Party1          | 1600            | 4.7               +
+ Party2          | 1422            | 3.7               +
+=======================================================+
```

So, it should omit the cities and sum the vote counts and percentages of each party. My current query:

```
SELECT City, PartyName, VoteCount, VotePercentage
FROM elections
ORDER BY PartyName
```

I've tried GROUP BY PartyName, but then it only shows me a fraction of the rows that should appear. How could I get the result in the table above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this as your query:

```
SELECT PartyName, SUM(VoteCount), SUM(VotePercentage) 
FROM elections 
GROUP BY PartyName
```

Comment: That was quick. Thanks that did the trick, I can accept in 10 mins ;)

Comment: @erol_smsr You may want to add `ORDER BY PartyName ASC`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks Raymond, looks better this way indeed :)