# Calculating sum line by line in SQL

Tags: sql, row

I am trying to calculate the transaction history/account balance for Account_ID 1 for the data below.

[image]

The goal is to get the following (starting balance at 500 and then one transaction which puts the balances to 400)
[image]

Is there a way in SQL to calculate the values row by row?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534819/sum-the-values-of-multiple-rows-with-the-same-column-value-in-mysql

Comment: The use of SUM be the way to go, not sure how efficient this is though if it's ran often?